# Populating a Volume Select Menu | Bash

Tags: bash, terminal

Trying to get a clean list of volumes mounted on the system

I used the following code for creating an array

```
volumes=(`df -i | grep -ioh "\Volumes\S*"`)
```

Problem is that it also returns unuseful mounts like

> Volumes/Data/home
>   Volumes/Data

This data will be used in a select menu, where the user can select an external drive.

Os: macOs

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a volumes < <(
  df | head -n -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1
)
```

- `IFS=$'\n'`: Sets the **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator to newline.
- `read`: Reads variable.

  - `-r`: Do not interpret backslashes.
  - `-d ''`: Sets the Bash's built-in record delimiter to null.
  - `-a volumes`: Reads the array variable `volumes`.
  - `< <(commands)`: Redirects read from the output of the commands.
- `df`: Lists mounted volumes with information.
- `| head -n -1`: Strips the header line from the stream.
- `| cut`: Cuts-out columns fields from the stream.

  - `-d ' '`: Delimits column with space.
  - `-f 1`: Selects first column.

Alternatively if the `head` command does not allow a negative index, use `sed 1d` to delete the first line for the stream:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a volumes < <(
  df | sed 1d | cut -d ' ' -f 1
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Léa Gris, getting: head: illegal line count -- -1

Comment: use `sed 1d` instead:

Comment: @Adrian Added alternative for you

Comment: volumes=('df')

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a volumes < <(
  df | sed 1d | cut -d ' ' -f 1
)


echo "$volumes"

Comment: that returns /dev/disk1s5 which is my root. What i want to do is list mounted volumes under /Volumes

Comment: ls -l /Volumes lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 Apr  4 15:34 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxr-xr-x  10 wolf  staff  320 Mar 26 12:11 root

Comment: but it needs to return the full path with slashes included e.g: /Volumes/usb-drive

Comment: the end result is the user selecting a volume, and then the script creates directories on that volume, and copying files, etc . So it is basically a prep script